# tieing different gauge of speaker wire together for one speaker

Tags: speakers

I am running speaker wire around the room but I've run short for 2 of em 
can I safely tie 2 different gauge of wires together for one speaker

Comment: How many watts? What are the two gauges? If you get too fine a wire, sound quality will be noticeably degraded. Stranded14 gauge lamp cord, by the foot/meter from the hardware store makes pretty good speaker wire. If you've 100 rms watts or more per channel, 12 gauge would be a better choice soundwise.

Answer (score 2):

Using two different gages of wire is no worse than just using the thinner gage of wire; switching won't harm anything (as long as the connection is done properly).

As for the minimum gage to use, when I was at MIT I ran 150' of #24 double twisted pair stranded wire from the stereo in my room to my speakers in the courtyard. It sounded fine to me. Quite possibly I had/have tin ears, but I'm sure the results weren't awful. So, unless you're using extremely thin or extremely long cables, you'll be fine. (The humongous, finely-stranded, oxygen-free speaker cables you'll find sold for an arm and a leg are just silly.)